# Windows 10 Problems: Applications don't show in Volume Mixer

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app, volume-mixer

So I just upgraded to Windows 10 from the Windows 8.1 ... and I noticed that the Volume Mixer just turns up and down for everything in general. I want to be able to turn down Chrome's sound and Skype's up at the same time. Just wondering how to fix this.

This is what I want to see:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fennd.png]

But THIS is what my volume has:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm7zU.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

#### Applications don't show in Volume Mixer

This functionality was removed from Windows 10.

You can use an application called [EarTrumpet](https://github.com/File-New-Project/EarTrumpet) instead:

[image]

---

#### Getting Volume Mixer for Modern Windows App

> The volume mixer for desktop mode limits the all access pass to only
>   the desktop applications. If you wish to get similar functionality for
>   the Modern Apps, you will have to install EarTrumpet application on
>   your computer. Simply download the .exe file on your computer and run
>   the setup file.
>
> After the application is installed, you will see a trumpet icon in the
>   system tray, from where you can control the sound of individual
>   applications for the modern apps. Also, as this is an individual
>   application, you can use it in parallel to the desktop volume mixer.
>
> [image]
>
> The app is very useful in instances where you are playing a modern
>   game on Windows 10 and at the same time listening to some songs on the
>   Edge browser. You can lower the volume of the game and enjoy the song
>   at the same time. This is just one of the many scenarios where it can
>   prove to be useful.

Source [Selectively Control Volume of Modern and Desktop Apps on Windows 10 Simultaneously](http://www.guidingtech.com/49691/selectively-control-volume-windows-10/)

Comment: I have this feature in Windows 10 (anniversary edition)

Comment: @nl-x Then it would seem that MS added it back to anniversary edition...

Comment: I do hoever miss Edge for example... I understand that "metro" applications are simply not implemented in the mixer

Comment: @nl-x Did you try the EarTrumpet program mentioned in the answer?

Comment: I have heard that EarTrumpet would support it. But I just don't like installing many 3rd party apps and plugins. So I just use FireFox and Chrome for my music

Comment: @nl-x No problem - of course both Firefox and Chrome are 3rd party apps :)